# how create address for each ethereum user

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, dapps

I have a group of Ethereum users how do I create an address for each user to  send their data on the network??
I want a way to create addresses for each user??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few different options to generate public and private key pair:

1. **ethers.js** - https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet ( also brings the option to create HD wallets. )
2. **web3.js** - https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-accounts.html#create
3. **keyethereum** - https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum

Each one of them also have the option to generate keystore files ( encrypted private key with secret password ).

Comment: Is it the same if I use ganache ??
Or the addresses there differ from these addresses

Comment: Ganache is just running a personal blockchain for your testing purposes. Generating pair of public and private key has nothing to do with blockchain action, what I mean is when you generate the pair you will not see anything in the Ganache logs ( no transactions is made ). If you want to manage these newly generated addresses balances then you need to unlock the accounts ( import them ) into the blockchain you are running.

Comment: Then inside the dApp project ( which should be connected to the port where Ganache blockchain is running ) you can use one of the options I listed for you in my answer.

Comment: I did not understand what you say
If i want to give each user an address on Ethereum so that he can send the data that he has to be saved
If I create an address with the private key and the public key, how will I specify this address in the Python file or how will I send the transaction through it? How will he have an ether ?? How will I track this transaction ?? I don't really know
I am really sorry, I am a beginner with this topic